# same custom field for single posts

Tags: custom-field, blog

I have a custom field for my blog page that displays a "custom title" in the header. When i click one of the blog posts on that page the "custom title" isn't there. I would like it to be the same custom field as the blog page for all single posts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you show the field on the blog page?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the same code for displaying "custom title" into your single.php
like this

```
$custom_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom fields name',true);
echo $custom_title;
```

Comment: **Please**, put more effort into your answers. A vague hint is not answer, an explanation and an example is.